# Power BI Enterprise Gateway Install - Failed to contact gateway service

Tags: installation, powerbi, gateway

I am trying to install and configure Power Bi Enterprise Gateway on a Windows 2016 server. I get "Failed to contact gateway service" error and another error below it "Network access to azure service bus is limited" and can't get to the configuration part. Any ideas what is the IP/ server it is trying to connect to and over what port?

[image]

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Do you check everything from this list?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-tshoot#troubleshoot-configuration

Comment: I don't get this point. The software was installed by server administrator on the server. However since that person doesn't have PowerBi account I login to configure it. Once I provide my account it says "checking a few things" and fails. The error in the log is: Error retrieving gateway configuration. Please ensure your gateway is running on the local computer and it is updated to the latest version.
Exception message: Access is denied. ---> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAccessDeniedException: Access is denied.